# Медленная удаленная сборка на Linux из под MS VS

Tags: linux, visual-c++, netbeans, компиляция, g++

Даны: проект (C++), VPS сервер (Ubuntu), MSVS 2015 update 2, Netbeans 8.0.2.

Проводим удаленную сборку на сервере, из Netbeans - общее время минута с небольшим хвостиком.

Проводим удаленную сборку на сервере, из MSVS - общее время шесть минут.

Замечено, что в первом случае процессор на сервере загружен и соответствующий компиляции процесс постоянно находится в топе. Во втором же случае процессор не грузится и компиляция лишь изредка находится в топе - работает как бы на фоне.

Что и как нужно изменить (прописать, галочки убрать/поставить), чтобы ускорить сборку с использованием MSVS?

Comment: исходники одни и те же? собираются одной и той же командой?

Comment: @alexander barakin Исходники одни и те же. Команды сборки под MSVS найти не удалось ни на сервере ни локально.

Comment: а каким образом вообще всё происходит? каким образом *netbeans* и *msvs* подключаются к другой операционной системе? я думаю, стоит об этом упомянуть (хотя бы ссылками на руководства) прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @alexander barakin Подключаются по ssh... А какая разница в целом как происходит процесс подключения, открытия файлов и т.п.? С таким же успехом можно спросить и ссылку на руководство, где описано открытие файла с диска. Это не есть что-то необычное для этих IDE - удаленная сборка "вшита" в них. Кто пользовался - тот знает. А кто не использовал таких возможностей - ответ от тех как бы и не ожидается.

Comment: способ подключения важен для попытки помочь определить, какие именно команды *msvs* и *netbeans* запускает. но вы правы, я никогда в жизни не пользовался ни *msvs*, ни *netbeans*, потому, действительно, ничего не смогу подсказать по поводу именно этих программ.

Comment: @alexander barakin Netbeans открывает созданный же в нем проект (проект был заранее закачан по ssh на сервер). Т.е. он ничего локально не "держит". Основа проекта - Makefile. Сами правила сборки все как на ладони. MSVS созданный локально проект закачивает на сервер (закачивает только рабочие cpp и h файлы). Сам файл проекта (vcxproj) остается лежать локально. В нем нет правил сборки. На сервере при сборке MSVS никаких файлов, кроме объектных и итогового, дополнительно не создается.

Comment: @alexander barakin Вся проблема в том, что сборка происходит, к этому вопросов, не имеется. Но время сборки с использованием MSVS просто удручает. Возможно, какие-то флаги и правила сборки будут отличаться (и там и там ручками специально ничего не выставлялось - все по умолчанию), но так, чтобы они повлияли на время сборки, увеличив его в 6! (шесть) раз...

Comment: одно лишь копирование файлов туда и обратно занимает время. а что за «процесс, соответствующий компиляции» запускает *msvs*?

Comment: @alexander barakin То, что копирование файлов занимает время - это понятно. Но общий размер cpp и h файлов ничтожен (хотя и в том и в другом случае файлы уже на сервере и закачивать их повторно для IDE не имеет смысла, ну кроме измененных), а списать на время закачки 5 минут не получится. Тем более, что MSVS описывает свои действия видом Copying sources remotely to 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', Starting remote build, Linking objects и четко видно на что это время уходит. Более того, как я указал в теле вопроса, разница именно в использовании процессора в процессе компиляции.

Comment: @alexander barakin Процесс, соответствующий компиляции, и в том и в другом случае один и тот же - `cc1plus`.

Comment: тут можно, конечно, изложить много теоретических предположений по поводу того, что в двух разных случаях могут запускаться вообще разные программы (или одна, но разных версий) с разными параметрами, переданными через комнадную строку или переменные окружения, и т.д. и т.п., но без конкретики — что именно запускают *msvs* и *netbeans*, всё это останется лишь теоретическим умствованием.

Comment: как я понял, по поводу *netbeans* определённость есть — она запускает программу *make* (которая интерпретирует *makefile* известного содержания). а вот *msvs*, как я понял из приведённой вами информации, самостоятельно запускает неизвестный набор команд с неизвестными параметрами и переменными окружения. // вы пробовали вручную повторить то, что делает *netbeans*: запустить *make* и засечь время сборки? оно сильно отличается от «результатов» *netbeans-а*?

Comment: @alexander barakin Да. Вы все верно поняли. Повторить то, что делает Netbeans попробовал - время практически не отличается от нетбинсовского (может быть меньше на 3-5 сек). При этом процессор ожидаемо грузится непрерывно и `cc1plus` всегда в топе.

Comment: приходит в голову такой критический для времени сборки, осуществляемой программой *make*, момент, как [Parallel Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html). что, как я понимаю, неосуществимо в случае «пошагового» вызова компилятора/линковщика/и т.п,, который, судя по всему, осуществляет *msvs*.

Comment: @alexander barakin Никаких особых опций (вида -j) нет в правилах сборки у Netbeans. Но дело даже вряд ли может быть в них - процессор на сервере одноядерный. Никакое распараллеливание не будет иметь выигрыша перед последовательным выполнением (даже скорее наоборот).

Comment: широко распространённая практика в *makefile-ах* — запуск *sub-make-ов*, которым можно передать (в том числе и) опцию `-j кол-во`.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что vcxproj лежит локально, и MSVS его парсит и **для каждого файла** шлёт команду компиляции на удаленную машину, ожидает ответа и т.д.. В отличие от нетбинс, который просто дает команду на сборку и всё.
Есть вероятность, что в рамках настроек MSVS проблема не решается. Но можно выяснить более точно. См. Comments.

Comment: Я догадываюсь о таком положении дел. Но в целом вопрос ставится так: что нужно изменить в MSVS, чтобы пофиксить подобное поведение? Хотя в целом, клиент может долбиться хоть десять раз при отправке команды на компиляцию файла. Это в любом случае не оправдывает такое время. Вы представляете себе мизер размера самой команды? Думаете она передается на сервер какое-то значимое время? Или думаете, что при этом устанавливается заново соединение? Я так не думаю. Там этих команд не более 30. По 10 секунд на передачу команды? Да и Makefile не общим чохом запускает команды в обработку, а по порядку.

Comment: Про галочки в MSVS ничего не скажу, не работал. А вот до сути проблемы докопаться - это можно попробовать. А вот уже поняв суть, можно искать пути решения. Wireshark'ом приходилось пользоваться? Он мог бы наглядно показать, что происходит в сети, с таймстампами и т.д. Советую. Сейчас ещё подумаю...

Comment: Мысли вслух.. не более 30 - полезная инфа, т.е. проект мелкий. Время уходит не на собственно передачу, а на всякие ожидания и переключения с передачи на приём.. Установление соед. заново - очень вряд ли, но исключать нельзя.. Я и не такое видел. :) Кстати, сервер в одной локалке с клиентом или реально "удалённый"? ... по порядку - в том-то и дело, общим чохом было бы куда быстрее... Жаль, что я с Msvs не работал.. На Eclips'е сейчас, я в embedded systems.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/90121)

Comment: @Streletz Я в курсе, надо же было как-то начинать.. Answer я просто удалю, мы его ищем совместно с топик-стартером в комментах. Или это тоже запрещено? Тогда не знаю, как и быть...

Comment: @A.Toumantsev сервер реально удаленный.

Comment: @MaxZS угу, понятно. Max, вы б мне подняли репутацию-то, а то ни черта делать нельзя... Я на англоязычных вариантах Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange в основном, можете поискать. А по вопросу: 1. WireShark совершенно необходим для любой отладки сетевых вещей, без него - игра вслепую. 2. Как я написал в ответе - вряд ли проблема решается в рамках VS, нужно найти режим работы, в кот. генерится makefile, кладется на сервер вместе проектом и сборка происходит прямо на сервере - клиент только получает конечный результат. Но это вряд ли, то что вам надо...

Comment: @A.Toumantsev я еще добавлю, что ssh может и минуту соединение устанавливать, если у него включены но не настроены методы аутентификации и обратный DNS

Comment: @A.Toumantsev Если бы у Вас была достаточная репутация на англоязычной (или любой другой) ветке SO, то Вам бы автоматом сотку репы накинули бы и на русскоязычную ветку (ну и наоборот). Ну а что касается самого вопроса, то в том то все и дело, что не могу найти подобного режима, не могу найти настроек, которые бы повлияли на саму сборку, на ее правила, на ее режим. А смотреть сетевую активность в данном случае можно, но это не решит проблемы. Можно изначально не глядя принять тот факт, что команды передаются по отдельности. Но как исправить это - вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: @gbg Что касается ssh, то замечено, что он длительное время будет устанавливать соединение, если вместо ip адреса ему подсунуть домен. Это не тот случай. Да и вряд ли он каждый раз его устанавливает. Ну и в целом, повторюсь, я как бы осознаю, что вероятно проблема именно в пошаговом запуске на компиляцию каждого файла. Но, во-первых, с моей точки зрения, это все равно не оправдывает шестикратного увеличения общего времени. А во-вторых, вопрос в том, как это изменить. Аналогия... У меня насморк. Я осознаю это и догадываюсь о его причинах. Но меня интересует лекарство :)

Comment: @MaxZS "Если бы у Вас была достаточная репутация на англоязычной" - а "достаточная" - это скока в граммах? :) Не, сотки у меня на SO нету, я недавно этой ерундой увлёкся... На StackExchange - есть. По вопросу - а English'ем владеете? Надо на MS Knowledge Base искать, не у вас у одного такая затыка, наверняка. MSVS - локализованная или англоязычная? Какая версия, кстати - 2013, 2015? что там еще бывает.... UPD: Я смотрю народ жалуется на тормоза VS *в принципе*, вы пробовали свой проект локально собрать? Может, это VS еле шевелится, а мы тут про сЕти развели бодягу...

Comment: @A.Toumantsev не помню сколько, но не так уж и много, наверное, 200 на какой-либо ветке. Что касается поиска на иных ресурсах - думаю, что дойду и до этого. И не думаю, что локализация MSVS имеет отношение к вопросу (ну а вообще - англоязычная). И конечно же локально проект собирается намного быстрее.

Comment: ладно, ухожу в реальную жизнь, суббота все-таки. Локал-ция к тому, что если я найду какие-то настройки - надо ли их на русский переводить :) Вот попалась такая ссылка [VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/features/usability/fastremote.php), это не про решение проблемы, но как бы намекает, что не только у вас Remote Build происходит slow. Как и ряд других ссылок, что Гугль дает. Последний (пока) вопрос - клиентская машина - Linux or Windows? Вроде бы не упомянуто нигде. [а всё-таки wireshark помог бы наглядно увидеть разницу между MSVS & Netbeans].

Comment: @A.Toumantsev MSVS нет на Linux. Есть VS Code - но это скорее некий текстовый редактор с элементами IDE. Полноценной IDE его называть еще, на мой взгляд, очень рано.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev недавно дошли руки до данного вопроса, и увидел на сервере в логах авторизации, что на каждую закачку файла MSVS открывает и закрывает сессию (логинится каждый раз). Т.е. Ваше в комментариях предположение `Установление соед. заново - очень вряд ли, но исключать нельзя.` оказалось наиболее правильным. Самое обидное, что это никак не фиксится (ну или пока не найдено мной). И удивляет в принципе, как можно было так наговнокодить (другое слово не подходит) в таком программном продукте. Хоть это и не решение вопроса, но, предлагаю Вам оформить свой коммент в виде ответа и я его приму.

Comment: Понял. В жизни бывает всё. ;-) оформить пока не могу: некогда.

Comment: @MaxZS Оформлять ответ не буду - реально некогда, да и интерес потерян. Но вам советую оформить ответ на свой собственный вопрос - другим пригодится.